# Forcing superscripts to overlap with other text for a controllable amount of text

Tags: superscripts

Say I have something like:

```
First author,\textsuperscript{1,2,3} Second author,\textsuperscript{2,3} Third author, etc.
```

Is there a way to make the superscripts start in the same location where the comma separating the authors start? In the example above, for the first author, I would like the superscript `1` to be right on top of the first comma, while for the second author, I would like the superscript `2` to be right on top of the second comma.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `\kern -3pt` is not very good, since you don't know the width of a comma.  What about this?

```
First author\rlap{,}\textsuperscript{1,2,3}
Second author\rlap{,}\textsuperscript{2,3} Third author, etc.
```

Explanation: `\rlap{whatever}` sets `whatever` "to the right of the current position", but making it occupy zero width.  (There is also `\llap`, and `\clap` in the `mathtools` package.)

Answer (score 3):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

First author,\kern-3pt\textsuperscript{1,2,3} Second 
author,\kern-3pt\textsuperscript{2,3} Third author, etc.

\end{document}
```

looks ugly to me ...

Comment: Thanks @Herbert. This is probably a personal question about aesthetics, but what would you prefer from the next three options?: *1)* Comma followed by superscripts, *2)* Superscripts followed by comma, or *3)* Superscripts overlapping with comma

Comment: the first one if it refers to the author(s) and second if the reference belongs to the part of the  sentence

Comment: Personally, I sometimes do `foo,\!\footnote{bar}` - but not everybody likes that.  And for *exact* overlapping, see my answer.